# Не работает json_decode

Tags: php, json

Ошибка:

> Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string

Код:

```
$res = json_decode($curl->post('https://auth.qiwi.com/cas/tgts', json_encode(array(
    'login' => '+79999999999',
    'password' => '123123'
))));
$TgtTicket = $res->entity->ticket;
echo $TgtTicket;
```

Что по сути возвращает $curl->post...:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [entity] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user] => +79139962423
            [ticket] => TGT-391357-QO7amrRgf2kOPxhhxWdo9FZUrdIZhJLCIOQHbk6jMEjfLuSePg
        )

    [links] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [rel] => sts
                    [href] => https://auth.qiwi.com/cas/sts
                )

        )

)
```

Но json_decode не может почему-то это декодировать, хотя вроде всё верно.

Comment: `$curl` - это что за объект? Какой библиотекой/CMF пользуетесь?

Comment: Вы же сами написали что `$curl->post()` вам выдает `stdClass Object`. А `json_decode()` ожидает строку на вход.

Comment: @tutankhamun, https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class

Comment: Чертовски симпатично. Спасибо за наводку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет. Не верно. `json_decode` декодирует только строку, а вы готовый объект передаете. Что-то мне кажется что у вас `$curl->post()` самостоятельно все декодировал и вам дополнительно ничего делать не нужно.

**Дополнено**

Посмотрел исходники. `Curl::post()` автоматически парсит JSON и XML если заголовок ответа `Content-Type` соответственно похож на JSON или XML (например application/json или text/xml)

Comment: Всё верно, спасибо!